# Parsing optional recursive parser runs in infinite recursion

Tags: parsing, haskell, megaparsec

I'm currently writing a parser for ECMAScript 5 (as a toy). The standard dictates how logical or expressions should be parsed:

```
<LogicalORExpression> :
    <LogicalANDExpression>
    <LogicalORExpression> || <LogicalANDExpression>
```

basicly this is equivalent to

`<logicalOrExpression> = [<logicalOrExpression> ||] <LogicalAndExpression>`

but how should I parse this without running into an infite loop? My current parser obviously does:

```
logicalOrExpression :: Parser LogicalOrExpression
logicalOrExpression = do
    orExpr <- optional $ do
        e <- logicalOrExpression
        _ <- symbol "||"
        return e
    andExpr <- logicalAndExpression
    case orExpr of
        Just e -> return $ LogicalOrExpression (e, andExpr)
        Nothing -> return $ AndExpression andExpr
```

Thanks

Comment: `logicalOrExpression = sepBy1 (symbol "||") logicalAndExpression`?

Answer (score 3):

It's easiest to use [`megaparsec`'s built-in tools](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec-6.2.0/docs/Text-Megaparsec-Expr.html) if you need to parse a grammar of operators with precedence and associativity.

```
expr = makeExprParser term table
    where
        term = literal <|> parenthesised expr
        table = [[InfixL (string "&&" $> And)], [InfixL (string "||" $> Or)]]
```

For suitable definitions of `literal` and `parenthesised`, this'll parse a grammar of literal expressions composed with left-associative infix `&&` and `||` operators, with `&&` having greater precedence than `||`. Megaparsec takes care of the tedious work of generating an LL(k) parser, and produces correct (left-associative, in this instance) parse trees.

Of course JavaScript's expression grammar is much larger than two operators. This example can be straightforwardly extended to include (eg) unary prefix operators like `!`, postfix function calls, etc. See [the module's documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec-6.2.0/docs/Text-Megaparsec-Expr.html).

Comment: I saw that, but the problem is that this flattens the grammar into one single Expression type. I have to rewrite the grammar to be right recursive and then post process the AST

Comment: @SuperManitu Why?

Comment: Because I need to retain the AST from the Spec, I cannot simply flatten it out.

Comment: @SuperManitu Why? Don't read the spec as a prescriptive description of how your compiler should be implemented. The BNF in the standard specifies the language grammar - what programmers use - not the internal data structures used by an implementation of the language. The fact that Haskell `data` declarations look superficially a bit like BNF notation is a red herring.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson I had similar thought, but then I realized that if one were to write an ES parsing library, the user of such library would expect the same AST as in the spec. If instead one is writing a compiler, the associativity of `&&,||` is irrelevant, since their semantics is associative anyway.

Comment: @chi I don't think that's true. Looking at eg `haskell-src-exts`, you see [one massive `Expr` type](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-exts-1.19.1/docs/Language-Haskell-Exts-Syntax.html#g:8) comprising infix expressions, function application, variables, etc. Whereas in [the spec](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-220003) the grammar for expressions is broken into four declarations.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson I'm not claiming that Haskell types must correspond to non-terminals in the grammar. I think we agree on this. However, if the grammar makes an operator left-associative, the parser must (should) produce the AST in that way. If the only purpose of the parser is as a first step of a compiler, I guess it can chose a different associativity, when the semantics is not affected. (BTW, GHC parses all the infix symbols ignoring fixity declarations `infixl ...`, and then patching the AST later on, since it is simpler)

Comment: @chi The Megaparsec parser I described above will parse `&&` and `||` in a left-associative manner.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson I'd consider that to implement the spec faithfully, then.

Answer (score 1):

That grammar looks equivalent to

```
<LogicalORExpression> :
    <LogicalANDExpression>
    <LogicalANDExpression> || <LogicalORExpression>
```

which becomes

```
<LogicalORExpression> :
    <LogicalANDExpression> [|| <LogicalORExpression>]
```

In general, you need to rewrite the grammar in (roughly) LL(1) form, if possible.

Comment: No those two are not equivalent, as this changes operator associativity AFAICT

Comment: @SuperManitu That's true. If you need the original one, I guess you have to postprocess the AST. Left recursion is unfeasible in LL(1) parsers. You can also try `sepBy1` which gives you a list, which you can then associate as you wish before producing the AST.

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right, transform the grammer to be a right recursive one and then adjust the AST. Will have to play around a bit with that.

Answer (score 0):

The empty string matches this parser, which I believe, causes infinite recursion in Magaparsec. I think you are missing a "term" or "boolean" somewhere in your function. If I wrote `True || False` what would capture the first "True"

Comment: The whole point of the optional part is to eventually do not parse anything. If I would add any consuming character while it would fix the recursion, it would also not accept all valid strings any more

Comment: But you must grab *something* first otherwise you succeed forever without making progress.  What you have is, "A logicalOrExpression is a logicalOrExpression which is a logicalOrExpression which is a logicalOrExpression which is a logicalOrExpression ..."

Answer (score -1):

As I want to stay true to the spec in terms of the AST produced, I decided to switch to an Earley based parser and not parser combinators, as Earley's algorithm can handle left recursion.

If I would be OK with flattening the grammar, I would use the answer of Benjamin Hodgson